# magento 2 Notice: Undefined index: modules

Tags: magento2

Anybody please tell me how to write the below code under config tag.

```
 <modules>
      <Tagalys_MerchandisingPage>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
     </Tagalys_MerchandisingPage>
  </modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

etc/module.xml can be defined as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Tagalys_MerchandisingPage" setup_version="0.1.0">
        </module>
</config>
```

and registration.php is as below:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Tagalys_MerchandisingPage',
    __DIR__
);
```